# Are `stream.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>())` and `stream.print()` the same in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I've seen both `stream.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>())` and `stream.print()`, wondering if there is any difference between them at all.

Based on https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/b2a342c6a6ef154ed3c1a44826ce2be14e538386/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.java#L972-L973, they are essentially the same except for the `.name("Print to Std. Out")` part, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the same and `stream.print()` is just a shortcut for `stream.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>()).name("Print to Std. Out");` :

```java
@PublicEvolving
public DataStreamSink<T> print() {
    PrintSinkFunction<T> printFunction = new PrintSinkFunction<>();
    return addSink(printFunction).name("Print to Std. Out");
}
```